# How to shoot my whole life from first POV?

Tags: video, video-quality, hardware, action-cam, gear

I would like to shoot whole my life (24h, 365d etc) on video, like as through my eyes.

However I came to dead end trying to match recording times of modern action cameras, the battery change hustle, the storage challenge, the convienience and the privacy concerns of my surrondings...

Does the tech advanced so far to allow that? Are there any legal limitations (like GDPR) in place to forbit me doing this?

In the end, any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Get yourself an camcorder with DC IN. position it over your head and use mirrors. The power delivery will be a bitch but you can get some heavy duty batteries and backpack DC to AC converters. If the batteries drain out. You can strategically place other batteries to the spots you walk onto.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you really thought this through thoroughly. (what a sentence!)

On a serious note tho, it would mean that you always have to carry around batteries on you, enough for at least while you're awake, as well as storage devices which you'll want to backup, or at least have in a raid-system. All in all, it's firstly going to be very expensive.

Second, you will have to figure out a smart way to integrate a camera into your life. A simple solution could be to just strap a gopro to your head. This will be clunky, uncomfortable and not too pretty though. I believe the best option for you is to try and conceal the camera in some way, like buying glasses that have a camera in the frame or something alike.

Next, there's legality. As you already assumed, there are places and things that you are not permitted to film. There's also different laws in different states, countries and continents. If you go to europe, you (theoretically) would have to ask any person for a permit if that person is filmed in a way that he/she/it is distinguishable and doesn't get lost in a crowd. That will be a lot of work. Even in America, you will run into places and people you are not permitted to film more frequently than you might think. And: You will have to keep every document of permits you ever got, since you need the evidence in case someone asks you to show it.

And last storage. What you would want is probably a RAID-System, since it's way safer for your files which I assume will be very important to you. So, buying RAID-Servers with HDDs or SSDs for, say, 800-900tb? You usually run at about 100$ / TB with SSDs, which you'll probably need in order to write the video data fast. So the drives alone, excluding the RAID and server-systems at all, you'll run at about 100.000$ alone. That is not cheap.

Nonetheless, I am impressed with your ambition and hope you pull through, just know that it won't be a walk in the park.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the tech is advanced enough. That is not going to be the problem.

You can have a very small, low power camera - look at the ones drone racers use. They aren't high resolution, but that could work on your favour as well, as they won't use as much storage. They also cope reasonably well with differing light conditions.

You can power from a belt-mounted or rucksack battery, with hot swappable packs.

You can stream or upload continuously, assuming you are in an area with connectivity. 5G will make this very easy.

---

So, not a tech problem.

Regulations will cause you an issue. Some countries will require you to put very strong security in place, some may not let you film in public without permission, most won't allow filming of military establishments.

What do you intend to do with the footage? That will help determine what controls you will need, and where you will not be able to go. Surveillance laws will get you in trouble in some countries, and law enforcement may confiscate hardware at borders and demand access (possibly so they can use your footage) and what will your employer think? Will they let you run video cameras watching you logging in, working with documents, etc.

How will you deal with an attacker who gains access to your feed and decides to assault you live online? Do you upload live or use local storage and only upload intermittently?

This is a very large issue, which you need to think through - is some video (likely to be almost all boring) worth the hassle?